# Script for changing C++ class names

Tags: c++, perl, bash, sed, cygwin

I have moved my classes from a global namespace into a specific namespace.  I have also changed the class names.  I want to convert all my source files that use these classes to the new format.  I was thinking either a `bash` script using a `sed` file on Cygwin or executing a perl script.  I'm having troubles with the `bash` script.

Here's the process I'm trying to perform:

1. For each source file, *.cpp and
   *.hpp, recursively:
2. If the file contains an old class
   name, then convert the file.
3. End for.

My problem in `Bash` script is detecting if the file contains an old class name.  I was thinking of one `grep` statement for each class name:

```
for f in `find . -iname \*.[ch]pp`;
do
  if [ grep "Field_Blob_Medium" $f -eq 0 || grep "Field_Boolean" ]; then
      sed -f conversion.sed $f
  fi
done
```

An issue is that only one command can be in `Bash` if statement, using this syntax:

```
if grep "Field_Unsigned_Short" $f;
```

so I can't do a logical OR of `grep`s.

I could perform a nested loop, but I don't know how to `break` out of a `Bash` for loop:

```
OLD_CLASS_NAMES="Field_Blob_Medium Field_Boolean Field_Unsigned_Int"
for f in `find . -iname \*.[ch]pp`;
do
  for c_name in $OLD_CLASS_NAMES;
  do
     if grep $c_name $f then
        sed -f convert.sed $f # <-- Need to break out of inner loop after this execution.
     fi
  done
done
```

So I'm looking for suggestions on how to process every source file that contains old class names and convert them to new ones.  A Cygwin `Bash` script example is preferred, although a Perl script would also be acceptable.  **Also, the script should make a backup copy of the original source file before writing the converted contents out to the `new` file.**

I'm running Cygwin on Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Comment: cant You just use grep with multiple regexp's?

grep -e "Field_Blob_Medium" -e "Field_Boolean" -e "Field_Unsigned_Int" ...

?

Comment: to make backup of every processed file:
sed -i.bak -f convert.sed $f

Comment: `break` breaks out of `for` loops and you can do `if prog || prog || prog` for logical OR (but regex alternation is better in this case). `for` with `find` is usually a bad idea because it fails when filenames have spaces. It's better to pipe `find` into `while`.

Comment: @Dennis:  Please give example of piping `find` into `while`.

Comment: @lollinus:  I have tested `grep` with multiple expressions and it is working on Cygwin.

Comment: `find . -type f -iname "*.[ch]pp" | while read -r f; do some_stuff_with "$f"; done` - Note the quotes around the variable `"$f"` - that protects the spaces, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't shy away from Perl: it makes this sort of task easy!

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -i.bak

use warnings;
use strict;

my $old = join "|" => qw(
  Field_Blob_Medium
  Field_Boolean
  Field_Unsigned_Int
);

chomp(@ARGV = `find . -iname \*.[ch]pp -print0 |
               xargs -0 grep -lE '($old)'`);

unless (@ARGV) {
  warn "$0: nothing to do!\n";
  exit 0;
}

while (<>) {
  s[Field_Blob_Medium]  [my::ns::MediumBlob]g ||
  s[Field_Boolean]      [my::ns::Bool]g       ||
  s[Field_Unsigned_Int] [my::ns::UInt]g;

  print;
}
```

The `-i` switch is for in-place editing. It automatically creates backups and writes the transformed results to the original locations.

Setting `@ARGV` makes it as though you had invoked the program with only those `*.cpp` and `*.hpp` files that contain the old class names. The `-E` switch to `grep` enables extended regular expressions so unescaped `(`, `)`, and `|` are metacharacters.

If there were no hits (*i.e.*, if `@ARGV` is empty), then there's nothing to do.

Otherwise, for each line of each file that has the old names (the mechanics of which Perl handles for you!), try to rename `Field_Blob_Medium` to `my::ns::MediumBlob` and so on. Note that these substitution attempts cease after the first success, so if a line contains two different old names, one will be replaced and the other will remain the same.

Usually the substitution operator is written `s///`, but you may use bracketing delimiters as above. I did so to left-justify the new names.

Of course this is a stand-in for your actual substitution.

Finally, `print` the possibly-modified line, which because of `-i` writes it to the updated source file.

Answer (score 1):

This work on my linux. It manages the various things pointed by others :

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD_NAMES="(EField_Blob_Medium|Field_Boolean|Field_Unsigned_Int)"

find "$1" -name "*.hpp" -o -name "*.cpp" -print0 | \
   xargs -0 --replace grep -E "${OLD_NAMES}" {} && sed -i.save -f convert.sed {}
```

What is important :

- the -print0 option of find with the -0 of xargs manages files with spaces. It uses the 'null' ASCII char as a separator. The -0 option of xargs understands the 'null' char as a separator : you correctly manage filenames with spaces.
- the --replace option is used to replace the '{}' string by the current processed file
- the -i option of sed backs up the file with a .save
- The && work as a shortcut of if. The second part of the expression works only if the first part is true

Hope it helsp,
my2c

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex option for grep to give you more flexibility in your search. Per your example:

```
if [ grep "Field_Blob_Medium" $f -eq 0 || grep "Field_Boolean" ];
```

could be

```
if [ grep -E "(Field_Blob_Medium|Field_Boolean)" ... ];
```

You could string together those '|'s to your hearts content.

Plus you could merge your finds into your greps

```
find . -name "*.hpp" or -name "*.cpp" | xargs grep -E ...
```

... in case you want to simplify that loop there.